# How to skip some rows that have errors in django-excel using save_to_database()

Tags: django, django-excel

I'm usign `django-excel` library in my Django project, and I want to skip some rows before save it to the database using the `save_to_database()` method.

I have something like the following:

```py
file = form.cleaned_data['file']
file.save_to_database(
    model=MyModel,
    mapdict = fields,
    initializer=self.choice_func,
)
```

All is working ok but I want to validate the data before call `save_to_database` function. The idea to do it is to add the rows that are not valid in an array and return it to notify the user that those fields not were saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I achieved this goal returning `None` instead of the row in `self.choice_fun` function:

This function look like the following:

```py
def choice_fun(self,row):
    # Do whatever thing to validate your row
    if row[5] != SOME_VALUE:
        return None
    return row
```

I also used some global variables to check if some rows had errors, then I returned back that data to the response to give the user a feedback in some way.